# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel, Version=6.0.0.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function (HTTP Trigger) and trying to use EF. However, I keep having this error:

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: OrdersExportFunction. RazorLight: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This is my project config:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <PreserveCompilationReferences>true</PreserveCompilationReferences>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
        <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
    </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp" Version="1.5.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="RazorLight" Version="2.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Remove="Views\Shared\OrderSummaryByCustomerTemplate.cshtml" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <EmbeddedResource Include="Views\Shared\OrderSummaryByCustomerTemplate.cshtml">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Ring a bell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it is caused by cleaning dependencies that are already present on function host, but in different version.

You might want to add to your csproj

```
<ItemGroup>
    <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
</ItemGroup>
```

to avoid removing any dependencies which might cause different issues for function host or you can add

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FunctionsPreservedDependencies Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel" />
</ItemGroup>
```

to preserve selected dependencies only.

Related info:

[GitHub - Concerns of FunctionsPreservedDependencies #2349](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2349)

[GitHub - _FunctionsSkipCleanOutput/FunctionsSkipCleanOutput/FunctionsPreservedDependencies are solutions to a problem created by the Functions team #7601](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/7601)